# Distance to a polygon along the stream flow path

Tags: arcgis-desktop, watershed, arc-hydro

I'm using Arc Hydro Tool for watershed processing and management.
I'm in a stage where I need to calculate the distance of all cells in a raster (the study area) to some polygons along the flow path.
So for each cell in the output raster will be the distance from that cell to the polygon along the flow path and a null value if it doesn't drain to the polygon.

Is there any method I can achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Flow Distance](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/flow-distance.htm) tool will calculate the distance from each cell to the closest flow path. I believe you could change the polygons to polylines in the shape of the polygon and then use those lines as the stream network in the Flow Distance tool. So your inputs would be the polylines, surface raster, flow direction raster, and distance type (horizontal).

Comment: Thanks so much your suggestion worked. I already had drainage lines in the polygon already, so I clipped the drainage lines in the polygon and used them as the stream network.

Comment: Awesome! Glad to help!